# Django admin ignores dynamically generated form fields

Tags: django, django-admin, dynamic-forms

I'm trying to have the django admin display a model form with dynamically generated fields. I setup my form like this:

```
class EulogyTextForm(f.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EulogyText
        fields = '__all__'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(EulogyTextForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        for i in range(len(settings.MULTITEXT_LANGUAGES)):
            field_name = 'language%s' % (i, )
            self.base_fields[field_name] = f.CharField(disabled=True, initial=settings.MULTITEXT_CHOICES[i][0])
            field_name += '_text'
            self.base_fields[field_name] = f.CharField()
```

I have setup my admin like this:

```
class EulogyTextAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = EulogyText
    exclude = []
    form = EulogyTextForm
```

However, Django admin will not display my added fields. I have created a TestView to display the form. In the test view, the form is correctly displayed with the added fields. Why does Djang admin ignore the additional fields?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for your problem? I checked the comments from the answer below and I'm trying to find a solution for the same context as you (dynamic fields for a JSON field in the model). I tried overriding the admin "get_fieldsets" and I got a "FieldError" exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly list your form fields in `fields` option

```
class EulogyTextForm(f.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EulogyText
        fields=[field1, field2, generated_fields...]
```

Comment: I tried doing that but I get an error that I'm trying to declare non existing fields.

Comment: @user2660930 declaring `fields` on `ModelForm` but not  `EulogyTextAdmin`

Comment: I don't want the fields to be declared on the model. The model has a JSON field. In the JSON field I'm storing pairs of strings, for example {'en-us':'example text'}. For each pair of strings, I want form fields. When I validate the form, the values from these fields will all be stored in the JSON field.